# What proof do I have that I own a token?

Tags: wallets, tokens, jaxx, address.transfer

I bought some tokens using the mnemonic phrase of my Jaxx.io wallet through myetherwallet. I got a confirmation in the tansaction history of Jaxx and a transaction ID (etherscan)
The token is https://adshares.net/ and it ends in 14 days

How do I receive the gains from owning this token and what proof do I have that I own this?

Also, how can I send these to another wallet?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the transaction ID?

Comment: 0x44cdaa7512e1abda3ae8d8fecfba2b528dbf6bfc6d37356ded64a0a45df55244

Comment: That transaction ID is invalid ??

Comment: Can you see the token balance in your Jaxx wallet?

Comment: In jaxx, I see who it is sent to with a transaction ID. As I usd MEW to buy the contract, I can see the token in Jaxx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the token , so you gains now come in 2 fold:

1. The utility you derive from been able to use the token to access the company's services
2. The change in value of the token as time progresses. If the token is listed on an exhange, you can monitor its value with apps like Delta or Blockfolio and send them to the exchange to be traded. If they arent, you should check out Etherdelta. Its a decentralised secondary marketplace where holders trade tokens.